# How do I horizontally center DecorationRole icon in QTableView cell?

Tags: c++, qt, view

There have been similar posts where the accepted solutions involve utilizing a custom delegate. Well, I've subclassed QStyledItemDelegate and overrode the paint function. Then, I set the delegate appropriately. Here is the paint override code:

```
void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    QStyleOptionViewItem opt = option;
    opt.decorationAlignment = Qt::AlignCenter;
    QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, opt, index);
}
```

Unfortunately, this does not center my icon horizontally. Interestingly, setting `opt.decorationPosition` to enum values `Top` or `Bottom` does allow horizontal alignment, but I don't want such positioning.

So then, how do I horizontally center these icons in my view?

---

EDIT:

I ended up manually drawing the icon like the solution linked at the top of my question suggests. I was looking for a more convenient method but this will do just fine.

Comment: What do you mean by `Top` / `Bottom` allowing for *horizontal* alignment? Not vertical?

Comment: @peppe There is no issue with vertical alignment, just horizontal. I'll edit the post to make that more clear.